# Query em duas tabelas sem INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, desempenho

Gostaria de saber, existe uma diferença em relação a performance dessas duas queries? no MySql

```
SELECT employee.*, company.name  FROM 
company,
employee
WHERE
employee.company_id = company.id AND
company.id = '365'
```

ou

```
SELECT employee.*, company.name  FROM 
company 
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.company_id  = company.id
WHERE
company.id = '365'
```

Comment: Performace em qual banco? a primeira consulta é utilizada em bancos antigos que não suportam a sintaxe/padronização `ANSI92(join)`.

Comment: Em Banco de dados MySql

Comment: Ok, edite a pergunte e deixe claro que é no `mysql`, pq  as tags estão com outros bancos.

Comment: Não imaginei que fosse fazer diferença em outros bancos.

Comment: A sintaxe pode ser a mesma mas os mecanismos internos de pesquisa dos bancos são diferentes ou seja tempos de resposta diferentes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Esta resposta pode não ser correta para este caso, mas acho valido compartilhar o conhecimento.***

O que é de meu conhecimento e experiencia, usar o `INNER JOIN` na verdade você está amarrando o método de busca e filtro que o banco irá utilizar entre as tabelas.
De certa forma é como impor ao BD: primeiro vai buscar o registro "pai" e depois o registro "filho".
Se você tem certeza do relacionamento , conhecimento do conteúdo dos dados e que este conteúdo não é dinâmico o suficiente para afetar o modo como você montou o seu relacionamento, o `INNER JOIN` sempre irá performar bem.

**Porém....** nem tudo é perfeito e é comum ver SQLs monstruosos ou "analíticos" sob dados, relacionamentos relativamente complexos e dados de tabela que com o tempo vão mudando (explico mais abaixo)

Quando usado o padrão "não-ansi" (sem a clausula JOIN) , você deixa aberto para que o otimizador do *engine* escolha o modo de busca dos dados e isso ele faz baseado nos indices das tabelas envolvidas e principalmente nas estatisticas colhidas dos dados.  (no caso do MySQL, comando `ANALYSE`).
Dependendo de como for o join, filtros, indices e amostragem de dados , o otimizador pode escolher buscar primeiro o registro filho e depois o registro pai... algo que o INNER JOIN não permitiria (não por questão técnica, mas porque isso está escrito nas regras ANSI, porém tenho duvida se o MySQL respeita 100% estas regras).

Copiando e traduzindo (google tradutor) o texto do [comando ANALYSE , manual do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html) :

> O MySQL utiliza a distribuição de chaves armazenadas para decidir a
>   ordem em que as tabelas devem ser unidas quando você executar um join
>   em alguma coisa diferente de uma constante. Além disso, a distribuição
>   das chaves pode ser usado no momento de decidir quais índices usar
>   para uma tabela específica em uma consulta.

## Update Statistics

É por isso que é comum ver em qualquer banco, quando alguém reclama de lentidão a 1a pergunta é : você atualizou as estatisticas?
Isso vale para MySQL, Oracle, SQL SERVER, Informix, Postre, etc...

---

## "Mutação" de dados...

Este exemplo é o que eu vejo mais comum de acontecer e facil de exemplificar.
Vamos supor uma tabela de pedidos de compras de um site, onde a tabela filha, de artigos comprados possui campos de status (Entregue, Pendente, Cancelado).

O montante da quantidade de pedidos com filhos em status Pendente é relativo ao que você filtra.

Se você tem uma base de dados com um bom histórico (milhares de registros), naturalmente o volume de status em Pendente será baixo... mas se olhar referente aos ultimos 2 meses, provavelmente será bem alto.
Dependendo do que você busca no seu SQL, ao relacionar a tabela Pai e Filha, filtrar o periodo e o status o *engine* pode considerar mais vantajoso e rápido iniciar a busca pelos registros dos filhos.

Vou tentar "desenhar" a situação:
Imagine :

- Tabela Pai de pedidos, com um historico de 5 anos e 100.000 registros de pedidos.
- Tabela Filha de artigos, com 800.000 registros (média de 8 artigos por pedido).
  Esta tabela possui a coluna de status e um indice sobre este status.
- Isso quer dizer que :
  800.000 artigos / 5 anos = 160.000 artigos por ano
  160.000 / 12 meses = 13.300 artigos por mes.

Supondo que a empresa mantem uma boa qualidade de entrega e dificilmente você verá pedidos com mais de 2 meses com itens em status *Pendente*...
(isso quer dizer no máximo 27mil registros de *artigos*)

Você quer buscar todos os itens pendentes...
Mas você escreveu o SQL assim:
`select * from pedido, artigos where pedido.pedido_id = artigos.pedido_id and artigos.status = 'P'`
Devido as estatisticas de amostragem de dados, há grande chance do banco escolher iniciar o filtro pela tabela *artigos* pois ele irá buscar no primeiro passo apenas 27mil registros e então depois muito menos registros na tabela *Pedidos*.

Mas se você escrever o SQL no modo ANSI ou se por algum o banco escolher iniciar a busca pela tabela *Pedidos* , ele irá buscar os 100.000 registros da tabela *Pedido* + os 800.000 registros da tabela *artigos* e então filtrar o status.
Isso ocorre porque o filtro está no segundo nivel da busca...

Claro que um filtro de período ajudaria, mas há casos em que a lógica de negócio não permitira o que acaba forçando o desenvolvedor escrever o SQL acima.

*Novamente... tenho duvidas se esta explicação se aplica 100% ao MySQL.*

Answer (score 3):

Não faz diferença. A única diferença é que na primeira query você tem um *implicit JOIN* e, na segunda, um *explicit JOIN*.

Antigamente tinha alguma diferença de performance sim (era preferível usar o *explicit JOIN*), mas hoje em dia não.

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente não faz nenhuma diferença quando as buscas são pequenas, pois para o usuário o resultado final é o mesmo. Porém, o `INNER JOIN` foi desenvolvido não somente para melhorar visualmente a sintaxe do código, más também para obter um pequeno ganho no desempenho que varia de servidor para servidor, más normalmente é cerca de 1%.

Ao utilizar o `INNER JOIN`, antes do servidor executar o `SELECT`, ele organiza a declaração em um plano, que é um conjunto de passos otimizados para coletar dados de forma eficiente.

Sem contar que o `INNER JOIN` faz parte e é recomendado pelo padrão ANSI.