# Qual a diferença entre unir tabelas por JOIN e WHERE?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, sql-select

Qual a diferença entre unir tabelas por `JOIN` ou por `WHERE`?
Exemplos:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes c JOIN enderecos e ON c.id = e.id_cliente;

SELECT * FROM clientes c, enderecos e WHERE c.id = e.id_cliente;
```

Isso é apenas uma questão de melhor *organização* do código ou se possui alguma diferença em relação ao *desempenho* também da consulta?

Comment: 2 considerações: Primeiro, não use somente join, use inner join, fica mais visivel. Segundo, sempre use a forma com inner join, pois além de ser mais legivel, você pode precisar colocar um left join depois e fica mais fácil e rápido de entender. Sobre sua pergunta não existe nenhum diferença.

Comment: [relacionada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10679/query-em-duas-tabelas-sem-inner-join)

Comment: Exceti pelo comentário do @marlon.tiedt, nenhuma resposta foi satisfatória quanto a parte da "melhor organização". Uma query com várias tabelas usando apenas o WHERE é quase impossível de ler.

Comment: Já eu prefiro usar apenas `JOIN` ao invés de `INNER JOIN`. Isso porque organizo meu código com identação à direita da primeira palavra de cada linha.

Comment: @marlon.tiedt Não entendi o que você falou sobre `left joins`

Comment: @Gabe, imagine uma SQL com 10 tabelas. Tudo funciona 100%. Ai colocaram uma nova tabela, `CLIENTE_TITULOS`. Se você fizer inner join, com a tabela cliente e não existir titulos, o cliente não irá aparecer. Agoara imagina você ter um SQL no padrão `clientes c, enderecos e left join CLIENTE_TITULOS`. olha como ficou fora do padrão. Fica mais bonito `clientes c inner join enderecos e left join CLIENTE_TITULOS`. Claro nos SQL acima omiti os campos por falta de espaço. Tendeu?

Comment: @marlon.tiedt Ah, entendi. Vocês dizer que usar sempre `inner joins` ao invés de "múltiplos" `wheres` torna mais "simples" (bonito :D) inserir um `right|left join` depois, se precisar. Faz sentido.

Comment: Isto mesmo...além de mais elegante, é mais fácil a manutenção

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Não há diferença, algebricamente as consultas são idênticas e terão a mesma performance.

Sua consulta abaixo esta escrita no padrão `ANSI 89`

```
SELECT * FROM clientes c, enderecos e WHERE c.id = e.id_cliente;
```

A mesma consulta escrita no padrão `ANSI 92`

```
SELECT * FROM clientes c JOIN enderecos e ON c.id = e.id_cliente;
```

Pessoalmente eu prefiro usar o padrão `ANSI 92`, por algumas razões:

- **Mais legível**, com os critérios de união separadas da cláusula `WHERE`, pois não se sabe a primeira vista se condições na clásula `WHERE` são filtros ou junções.
- **Menos provável que perca critérios de união**, na primeira consulta se não especificarmos o critério na cláusula `WHERE` o resultado será o produto cartesiano entre as tabelas clientes,enderecos
- **Evolução**, se o padrão ANSI 92 especifica operadores de junções específicas, por que não usá-los?
- **Flexibilidade**, uma junção na cláusula `WHERE` que tenha um efeito de `INNER JOIN` e posteriormente precise ser alterado para `OUTER` pode ser bem mais complicado

Answer (score 6):

Fazem exactamente a mesma coisa, são iguais tanto a nível de performance como o resultado obtido, apenas diferem na sintaxe.

Se quiser validar o que escrevi acima, utilize o comando EXPLAIN:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM clientes c JOIN enderecos e ON c.id = e.id_cliente;
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM clientes c, enderecos e WHERE c.id = e.id_cliente;
```

Veja que o mecanismo de indexação usado para obter os resultados são os mesmos.

Comment: A melhor forma de mostrar a diferença.

Answer (score 6):

Em relação a performance, ambos se equalizam. No entanto, note:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes c, enderecos e
```

Esquecemos da cláusula `WHERE` fazendo a ligação das chaves das tabelas. O resultado é um produto cartesiano. Utilizar `JOIN` impede a ocorrência de tais casos.

Comment: O correto seria *produto cartesiano*.

Comment: Válido, corrigido :-)

Comment: A propósito, dei *updote* porque foi a única resposta que falou do problema em se esquecer do where.

Comment: Pois é, não entendo esse lance de downvotes sem explicação. Não vejo nada errado com minha resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Não há qualquer diferença a não ser pelo código em si. Em relação a desempenho também não tem qualquer diferença.