# Como devem ser selecionados os dados de uma tabela através de junções?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Ao usar o `SELECT` para obter os dados da `tabela_A` efetuando uma junção com a `tabela_B`, normalmente, e crendo que a seja a forma correta, utilizamos alguns dos comandos `JOIN`. Ex:

```
SELECT codigo, nome FROM tabela_A a
INNER JOIN tabela_B b ON b.fk_tabela_B = a.codigo
```

Porém, a mesma condição eu consigo obter utilizando a seguinte sintaxe:

```
SELECT codigo, nome FROM tabela_A a, tabela_B
WHERE b.fk_tabela_B = a.codigo
```

O primeiro exemplo, possui uma leitura mais fácil, IMO, e o segundo exemplo poupa alguns caracteres.

- Mas qual a diferença no uso dos dois?
- Há questões de performance ou tratamento diferenciado dos dados obtidos?
- Posso dizer que apenas um dos exemplos é a maneira correta de se fazer?

Comment: [Qual a diferença entre unir tabelas por JOIN e WHERE?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15025/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os dois exemplos estão corretos, a performance é a mesma bem como os dados retornados serão os mesmos. A diferença que o primeiro poderá ser usado em qualquer sintaxe. Enquanto que o join varia de uma linguagem para outra. Espero ter lhe esclarecido.

No meu caso meus professores da faculdade ensinaram nas duas formas.